# Print content of a file with same extension in Multiple folders based on date and time

Tags: shell, unix, directory

Could I please know how I can print contents of the file with same extension (for example, .coords) in multiple directories to a text file using a shell script, confining to specific date and time of the directory created.

Would be thankful to your replies.

EDIT:

```
ls -ltr
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 prakkisr prakkisr 4096 Jul 28 13:23 A
drwxrwxr-x 2 prakkisr prakkisr 4096 Jul 29 09:56 B
drwxrwxr-x 2 prakkisr prakkisr 4096 Jul 31 12:15 C
drwxrwxr-x 2 prakkisr prakkisr 4096 Jul 31 14:34 D
```

All the folders A,B,C,D have a file which ends with .coords (a.coords in A folder, b.coords in B folder etc..)

Firstly, I want only those folders generated on Jul 31 (i.e C and D folder) to be accessed and want to print the contents of c.coords and d.coords files in those folder into a text file. ( this is according to date)

Secondly, Is it possible to print it according to time. Like suppose, I want only those ".coords" file from the folder (in this case 'D' folder), which are generated after time 14:00 today and get printed into another file. (this is according to date as well as time)

Comment: What are these extensions? Can you add more details and examples like output of `ls`, etc.?

Comment: Please specify your system as well and the version of the tools you're using: `date --version; find --version; stat --version; bash --version`

Comment: I am using ubuntu 13.04 system. date (GNU coreutils) 8.20, find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2, stat (GNU coreutils) 8.20, GNU bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I see. I think that would work with [John1024's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25052425/445221).

Comment: Hi. May I kindly request to vote my post? It seems I cannot comment on other posts unless i have reputation of 50. I now have 47.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will print the contents of all `*.coords` files that are in directories with a modification date within the last day:

```
find . -type d -mtime 0 -exec sh -c 'cat {}/*.coords 2>/dev/null' \;
```

If you wanted to see the names of the `*.coords` files rather than their content, then use:

```
find . -type d -mtime 0 -exec sh -c 'ls {}/*.coords 2>/dev/null' \;
```

The age of the directory can be specified in many other ways.  For example:

- To specify the directories age in minutes, use `-mmin` in place of `-mtime`.
- To specify the directories creation date, rather than its last modification date, use `-cmin` or `-ctime`.
- If your file system supports it, it is also possible to select directories based on their last access time.  Use `-amin` or `-atime`.
- It is also possible to select directories based some range in times by prepending the age with a `+` or `-` sign.  To select directories with a creation date more recent than two days, use `-ctime -2`.  By including two such specifiers, you can select from a range of dates.

See `man find` for full details.

#### Variation

Suppose that we want to search based on *the date of the file*, rather than *the date of the directory* in which the file resides.  In this case, a simpler command may be used to print the contents of the matching files:

```
find . -name '*.coords' -mtime 0 -exec cat {} \;
```

Suppose that we want to both print the file's name and its contents.  Then, we include to actions to the `find` command:

```
find . -name '*.coords' -mtime 0 -print -exec cat {} \;
```

Note the use of quotation marks around `*.coords`.  This assures that the command will work in case that the current directory happens to have `.coords` file in it.

Comment: The first command is what more suitable to me. Could I know, how to print the header of the file along with the contents. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I modified your asnwer to 
`find . -name *.coords -mtime 0 -print -exec cat {} \;` and got my result. Sorry could not upvote you. Low reputation here.:(